# Clarity Datagrid custom filtering isn't working with more than one filter

Tags: vmware-clarity

I created the non-working sample application here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-dwqmgr

The Role filtering is working, but the Group filtering is not.
The weird part is the datagrid is showing as if it is filtered, however the event sent as part of the clrDgRefresh does not have the custom filter for the non-working filter.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that this used to work with Clarity 1.0, but broke upgrading to 2.0.2

Comment: I think this is related to a couple of other the datagrid has that still need to be investigated: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/3486 and https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/3282.